# What is Target Device of IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME (USB driver specific IOCTL IRQ)

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, driver, wdk

I am a bit confused by the USB IOCTL **IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME**.  What is the target device of it? Although the MSDN WDK doc clearly indicates the target device, I am still confused by the USBVIEW sample provided by the WDK.  The reason I'm confused is as follows:

I am new to kernel mode and USB driver writing in Windows and is now studying the USBVIEW sample from the windows driver kit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558728(v=vs.85).aspx.  The MSDN describes the first step the USBVIEW sample performs as:

> Enumerate host controllers and root
>   hubs. Host controllers have symbolic
>   link names of the form "HCDx", where x
>   starts at 0.
>
> Use CreateFile() to open each **host
>   controller** symbolic link.
>
> Create a node in the tree view to
>   represent each host controller.
>
> After a host controller has been
>   opened, send the host controller an
>   IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME request to
>   get the symbolic link name of the root
>   hub that is part of the host
>   controller

But, I double checked the usage of IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537326(v=VS.85).aspx
which says:

> IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME is a
>   user-mode I/O control request. This
>   request targets the **USB hub FDO**.

Note that the target of the IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME IRP is a USB Hub FDO.  However, as described by the USBVIEW sample, we just retreived the host controller symbolic link which means the device object is a host controller device object.  How could we send it a IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME IRP?  Should we retreive a USB hub FDO somehow first?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's an unfortunate copy-paste error. `IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME` is indeed sent to the host controller and therefore handled by the USB Host Controller FDO.

By the way, just to put you in context:
The term "FDO" only loosely concerns user mode -- it's not like you can access any other "xDO" anyway. If you were to send this IOCTL in kernel mode, then sure, you can send an IOCTL to any specific device object in the device stack ("can" doesn't mean "should", mind you). However, a `DeviceIoControl` from a user mode application always sends IOCTLs to the top of the device stack (therefore it passes all the filters, the FDO and down to the PDO).

This question was asked on March 28, so I really hope you've solved it by now :)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states you will need a handle to the USB host controller but it is not very clear on how you are supposed to get such a handle. In USBView something similar to this function is used to get the device path name by passing `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER` (include `initguid.h` and `usbiodef.h`):

```
vector<wstring> EnumDevices(
    _In_    const GUID Guid
)
{
    vector<wstring> r;

    int index = 0;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&Guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DevInfoData;
    memset(&DevInfoData, 0, sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
    DevInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

    while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, index, &DevInfoData)) {
        index++;

        int jndex = 0;
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DevIntData;
        memset(&DevIntData, 0, sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA));
        DevIntData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

        while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
            hDevInfo,
            &DevInfoData, &Guid, jndex, &DevIntData
        )) {
            jndex++;

            // Get the size required for the structure.
            DWORD RequiredSize;
            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                hDevInfo, &DevIntData, NULL, NULL, &RequiredSize, NULL
            );

            PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pDevIntDetData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)malloc(
                sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + RequiredSize
            );
            memset(pDevIntDetData, 0, sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + RequiredSize);
            pDevIntDetData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                hDevInfo,
                &DevIntData,
                pDevIntDetData, RequiredSize,
                NULL,
                &DevInfoData
            );

            r.push_back(wstring(pDevIntDetData->DevicePath));
            free(pDevIntDetData);
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Keep in mind using the above function you can also request devices of type `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB` and `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE` which may eliminate any need to interact with the host controller or hubs directly.